# Stata does not replace variable value

Tags: replace, stata

Stata does not `replace` a value, as I am commanding. What is happening?
I have this variable `Shutouts`, which is a float variable (%9.0g).

One observation has the value = 5.08; that is an error, it should be 5.
I type: `replace Shutout= 5 if Shutout==5.08`.
And, surprisingly to me, Stata responds:

```
replace Shutouts=5 if Shutouts==5.08
(0 real changes made)
```

I have a similar problem for a variable with the same characteristics, with the name `Save_perc`; one value is 9.2 but should be .92. And, also this time, I receive this response from Stata:

```
replace Save_perc=.92 if Save_perc==9.2
(0 real changes made)
```

Why "0 real changes"?

It seems like a very banal problem, but I have been working on it for like 30' and I cannot really figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete and verifyible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read. For example, you do not include the error message in your question. Please do so.

Comment: thanks, I had forgotten to type some relevant info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it has to do with how floating numbers are stored into memory. You should not use `==` when comparing two different number formats because some internal storage approximation can make the comparison fail.

In your case, you should just use

```
Shutouts=5 if Shutouts > 5.07
```

or

```
  Shutouts=5 if Shutouts == float(5.07)
```

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly! I figured it was some problem related with the format of the data, but I could not put my finger on what was the problem. Thank you very much again! (sorry I cannot vote you UP yet, due to my low score on this chapter of the StackExchange platform)

Comment: It's nothing to do with format in Stata's sense, namely display format. It's entirely to do with precision. `search precision` for documentation.

Comment: hey nick yes i mean precision